# How to Configure CAS v4.2.7 to enable X.509 Authentication

Tags: authentication, certificate, cas, x509

What I have done

First, I cloned the repository of the CAS project from github and switched to the tag v4.2.7.
   
   `git clone https://github.com/apereo/cas.git
   git checkout v4.2.7`

Then I build using gradlew tool
`./gradlew`

Finally, I copied the artifact **./cas-server-webapp/build/libs/cas-server-webapp-4.2.7.war**, and extract it to run, it just works well.

But since I want to configure the CAS using the **X.509 Authentication** method, the result is frustrated, because the login web flow XML file is different: all of solutions to using a X.509 Authentication method say first to substitute the **generateLoginTicket** with **startAuthenticate** like this: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/X.509+Certificates, but the "generateLoginTicket" is gone in the file /WEB-INF/webflow/login/login.xml of the version 4.2.7. **And the documentation of the CAS is also of no help, https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/X509-Authentication.html**

```
I want to study how to configure the CAS v4.2.7 using a X.509 Authentication method. I would be appreciate if you could help me out.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal experience with 5.0 version overlay add to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
  <artifactId>cas-server-support-x509-webflow</artifactId>
  <version>${cas.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And add proper CA certificates to the server keystore.